# please guide me to solve?

Tags: linear-algebra

show
\begin{Vmatrix}
   1 & -(x_{1}+x_{2})&x_{1}x_{2}&0\\
   0 &1 &-(x_{1}+x_{2})&x_{1}x_{2}\\
   0&x_{1}+x_{2}-(y_{1}+y_{2})&y_{1}y_{2}-x_{1}x_{2} &0\\
   0 &1 &-(y_{1}+y_{2})&y_{1}y_{2}
\end{Vmatrix}
=$(x_{1}-y_{1})(x_{1}-y_{2})(x_{2}-y_{1})(x_{2}-y_{2})$

Comment: Hint: Expand down the first column.

Comment: which becomes the equivalent of finding $$\begin{Vmatrix}
  1 &-(x_{1}+x_{2})&x_{1}x_{2}\\
   x_{1}+x_{2}-(y_{1}+y_{2})&y_{1}y_{2}-x_{1}x_{2} &0\\
1 &-(y_{1}+y_{2})&y_{1}y_{2}
\end{Vmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2):

Develop along the first column  we obtain
$$\Delta=\begin{Vmatrix}
   \\
   1 &-(x_{1}+x_{2})&x_{1}x_{2}\\
   x_{1}+x_{2}-(y_{1}+y_{2})&y_{1}y_{2}-x_{1}x_{2} &0\\
   1 &-(y_{1}+y_{2})&y_{1}y_{2}
\end{Vmatrix}$$
If we don't want to do the calculus notice $\Delta=\Delta(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)$ is a polynomial of four variables and with leading coefficient $1$ and it vanishes if $x_i=y_j,\; i=1,2;\; j=1,2$, Can we conclude?

Comment: This plus will make your day merciful. :)